# Using sharepoint online excel file as a data source in SSIS

Tags: sql-server, excel, sharepoint, ssis

The user case is that we have a file in our SharePoint online that I need to load into our on prem SQL server, using SSIS 2019 (64 bit).

This question is about how to use SSIS to copy the file from the online SharePoint Document Library to an on-prem server file location, from the on-prem server I indeed to use SSIS to load the file data required to the on-prem SQL server

I have read a number of question

- [Opening Excel file stored on SharePoint as data source using ADODB Connection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28434783/opening-excel-file-stored-on-sharepoint-as-data-source-using-adodb-connection)
- [Import Excel file located in SharePoint Server into SSIS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50880220/import-excel-file-located-in-sharepoint-server-into-ssis)

However, in the main I am struggling to use the "Show in File Explorer" option even when I try to use IE11 Can any one suggest an easier way to convert the web file path to the correctly formatted  UNC

I am aware that I could use a Power Automate to move the file to achieve the same thing, but I am finding it strange that SSIS does not do this

Can anyone help please